# Run callback function whether Element exists or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whether the user just logged in or not, the HTML is generated like that:

User just logged in:

```
<body>
   <div id="welcomemessage">
   <div id="content>
</body>
```

User didn't just log in:

```
<body>
   <div id="content>
</body>
```

The jQuery code:

```js
$("div#welcomemessage").fadeIn(500,function(){
   //COMPLEX CODE
})
```

As the inner code is quite complex, I don't want to write it twice. So is there a way to execute this code without an if statement?

Comment: Without an if? Sure: `$("div#welcomemessage").length || $("div#welcomemessage").fadeIn(...)` - But probably not what you wanted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could write the complex code in a function and only repeat the function call:

```
var runComplexCode = function () {
    //COMPLEX CODE
};

if (/* exists element */) {
    $("div#welcomemessage").fadeIn(500, runComplexCode);
} else {
    runComplexCode();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that part of the code also depends if #welcome_message exists!

Comment: I've solved it with an own function and passing variables to it. Seems like it was just bad coded. Thanks for our help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap the logic in your own function?

If you're crazy you can promisify the whole thing and introduce some unnecessary complexity:

```
function $if(e) {
    $e = $(e)
    if($e.length) return Promise.resolve($e)
    return Promise.reject(e)
}

$if('#welcomemessage')
    .then(e => e.fadeIn(500, ...))
    .catch(/* do something else */)
```

While this works please don't actually use this. Don't make things more complicated than they need to be. (Unless you see any actual use in this approach.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that part of the code also depends if #welcome_message exists!

Comment: I've solved it with an own function and passing variables to it. Seems like it was just bad coded. Thanks for our help!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to extract your complex logic out in to its own function. You can then use an `if` statement (or ternary expression, as below) to direct your logic flow based on whether or not the `#welcomemessage` element exists in the DOM. Try this:

```js
var foo = function() {
  console.log('complex code here...');
}

var $welcome = $('#welcomemessage');
$welcome.length ? $welcome.fadeIn(500, foo) : foo();
```

```css
#welcomemessage { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="welcomemessage">Welcome!</div>
```

Comment: I've solved it with an own function and passing variables to it. Seems like it was just bad coded. Thanks for our help!